# When is it true that $\dim(U \cap (V+W))=\dim(U \cap V + U \cap W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I apologize if this is a silly question( which may have been asked before), I was wondering after seeing a post on this [list on math-overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23501#23501)

When is it true that $\dim(U \cap (V+W))=\dim(U \cap V + U \cap W$)?

This is not true in general, since we can set $U,V,W$ to be three distinct lines in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. For example, if if I set $U=\langle (1,0)\rangle$, $V=\langle (0,1)\rangle$, and $W=\langle (1,1) \rangle$. We then have that

$\dim(U \cap (V+W))=\dim(U)=1$

$\dim(U \cap V + U \cap W)=0$

I was just curious more than anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $U\cap (V+W)$ and $(U\cap V)+(U\cap W)$ are both vector spaces, with the former containing the latter, they have the same dimension exactly when they are equal.  Hence, the original question is true precisely when $$U\cap ((V+W)\setminus V\setminus W)=\emptyset$$

In the example given, $(1,0)\in U\cap ((V+W)\setminus V\setminus W)$.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be what I am looking for.  In the last line, did you mean $(1,0)$?

Comment: @user135520, quite right, thanks.  Fixed.